# AWS Cognito & Hasura - Delete user from hasura db when deleted in cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, hasura, incognito-mode

I have connected the `Post confirmation` trigger in AWS Cognito to a lambda that adds a row for the user in a hasura tabla via the exposed GraphQL API. I want to do the same for deleting a user but there doesn't appear to be a `User deletion` trigger in AWS Cognito. Is there a simple way to hook this event to hasura so it deletes the row in hasura when a user is deleted in cognito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could reverse the flow here...

How about having your user deletion process begin by deleting the user from the user table and have a hasura event handler for on delete from table that makes the API call to delete the Cognito user...?

Does this work?

Comment: Lol. That was fast!

Comment: That would work, just not as clean as I was hoping. Thanks for this though, will try that now.